# SQL DB design - One to many with temporary restrictions

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, one-to-many

I am trying to design the tables and relationships of a MySQL database and I am facing the following situation:

- I have a standard `incidences` table, with its `id` primary key and some others fields.
- I also have another standard table called `reports`, same structure.

The relationship between them should be `one to many` (**i.e., `1` report is generated from `n` incidences**). But the problem comes when defining the relationship because as far as I know, I should declare a `report_id` foreign key in `incidences` table, BUT incidences are temporally prior to reports, so when I create them I do not have that `report_id` information yet...

Does anyone have experience in such situation? How is it commonly resolved?

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can update the `incidences` table after the report is created.  Or use a junction table if one incident can be part of more than one report.

Comment: Update the report_id field later, once the report is known. Although, I'm not really sure what this report means :)

Comment: Thanks to both, but foreign keys should not be empty or null in a database as a rule. What should I do then? Fill it with a fixed number, e.g. 1, by default? It sounds a little bit clumpsy, isn't it? :S

Answer (score 0):

`FOREIGN KEYs` are not the end-all be-all`.  Simply have the incidences.report_id column, and declare it`NULL`.  When you get the`report_id`, then fill in the column.  Only if necessary, have an index on incidences.report_id.